# How It Works Links Seem Lame

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am in the process of working up a question for the Christianity Stack Exchange site but while doing so, I decided to play with the “Tell me more” / “Here’s how it works” box put at the top of the page. On the Christianity site, this can be seen by going to the bottom and selecting “Help”.

Now the issue is, I can select “Tell me more”, “Anybody can ask a question”, “Anybody can answer”, and – ‘the best answers...’ and all of them take me to the same location!?!

Maybe the “Tell me more” page should be reworked so there really are three different sections???

Of course, I might just be too picky - your call.

P.S. Also, no graphics (like sprite-herobox.png) are printed when I print a page with this block on it.

Comment: I'd expect it to work the same way as you did - surely this should be changed?

Comment: There are three different links each with a different graphics. I would expect them to maybe go to the same site, but a different topic / section of that site. Else why are all three different? Like I say, it just seems a little lame.